# Grant permission to word with a protected file

Tags: java, security, permissions, administrator

I need to programmatically edit, write or delete protected files. In Windows, if i do it manually, it asks for permission and in Unix systems i need "sudo".
How can I ask in Java for higher privileges during execution?

Comment: A lot of programs needs high privileges to work... i just wanna know hot to get them in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program requires high level access it is best to advise the user that they need to run it as root / a privileged account in order to work.
Otherwise the best option is to start a new 'proxy process' that is initialised using "sudo" and then a program doing what you want, eg "sudo cp File1 File2" that will perform your dirty work for you.
Unfortunately this is not cross platform and requires the users password.
There is simply no way you can just bump the JVM to a higher user during execution as this would pose a huge security risk.

md_5

Answer (score 0):

Because Java works using a virtual machine, you can't just start (for example) another thread in an elevated mode.  Instead, you'll need to launch an entirely new VM, which you won't be able to connect to.

I'd look into ways of executing a separate Java process which can run with elevated permissions.  You can still use the same code, but have it be a main method.

You won't be able to just raise your privillages.

I might be entirely wrong, and am happy to be shown otherwise.